# Route needs async data, where do I call the async function?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a screen which displays some data (vocabulary) loaded from a firebase. Therefore, when the screen is shown for the first time, it should await the async function (which is a method of a Provider) which loads this data. The data is then loaded into a local variable for later use. I also have a dropdown menu which can sort the data in different ways inside a setState. What I want to avoid is that the data is loaded from the firebase each time the sorting of the data changes because I think that would be inefficient.

What I initially did was having a FutureBuilder in the build function, which would wait for the Provider's asynchronous loading function. But then every time the sorting changes, the build method gets triggered and with it the load-function, which I'm trying to avoid.
I then tried putting the load-function into initState, but I can't do that since I don't have the context necessary to call the Provider.
Then I tried to load the data inside didChangeDependencies, but that got me a LateInitializationError since the build method isn't waiting for the data to finish loading.

What can I do? This is my first application and I'm still very new to Flutter, so I haven't managed to wrap my head around a lot of things. Help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the provider method static and you won't need the context

```
static Future<Map<String, dynamic>> makeGetRequest(String uriResource, Map<String, dynamic> bodyRequest) async {
final client = HttpClient();
Map<String, dynamic> result = Map.from(resultError);

try {
  final uri = Uri.http('$HOST:$PORT', uriResource, bodyRequest);
  HttpClientRequest request = await client.getUrl(uri);
  request.headers.set(HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader, contentJson);
  HttpClientResponse response = await request.close();

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    result = jsonDecode(await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join());
  } else {
    result['message'] = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
  }
} on SocketException {
  result['message'] = badConnection;
} on HttpException {
  result['message'] = serverUnavailable;
} finally {
  client.close();
}

return result;
```

}

Or you can add a variable higher up the tree, which stores either a dictionary or a flag that controls loading.
The third way is to create a separate class for loading and storing the dictionary, then the data will not be lost during rebuild. And inside the class already store the data loading flag.

There is another way using FutureBuilder. Make your Future static so it's only called once

```
late final Future load; <= declare

load = loadData(); <= assign value in initState

...FutureBuilder(
              future: load,... <= use

Future<bool> loadData() async {
...load your data...
}
```

Comment: Thank you. That's a good idea I believe. I will try making it static!